# IPAddress are returning different on LAN net and ZONG 4G

Tags: java, networking, ip

IPAddress are returning different on LAN net and ZONG 4G.

I want to know the IP addresses of clients in java application so i can restrict the users for login and other roles.
But problem is that when i run below code on LAN net it returns correct IPV4 address, But if I connect Zong 4G Device it only returns **192.168.10.100** on any computer.

How to get IP Address of client?

My code:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String ip = address.getHostAddress();
String host = address.getHostName();

System.out.println("IP Address = " + ip);
System.out.println("host= " + host);
```

Comment: @Eliwa no its not duplicate, totally different question.

Comment: does you tried to use public api for example like : http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com

Comment: @Eliwa not get please describe

Comment: Either your ISP or the Zong 4G does [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) -- and it's really common to have a [private network ip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) on your machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`192.168.10.100` mean that your client is behind the NAT. There is thing called [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) that may help you (I'm not expert and not really sure).

Alternative approach is to connect to server and ask it what it thing your IP is. It also have limitation, clients behind same NAT will have same IP.

In general building security based on IP address is bad idea.

Comment: Not get what should i have to do

Comment: Reconsider idea of basing security on client IP address.